# Run single test with jest.runCLI()

Tags: jestjs, gulp-jest

I want to use `jest.runCLI()` in `gulp` for executing only a changed test.

How can I do this?

How can I run just one test with `jest.runCLI()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jest has a CLI option to run only changed files (based on the git repository status).
The command line `jest --onlyChanged` becomes programmatically:

```
jest.runCLI({'onlyChanged': true}, __dirname, function (success) {...});
```

Using the terminal, jest uses non-hyphenated options to specified filenames:

- `jest test1` runs only test1.js
- `jest test1 test2` runs test1.js and test2.js

jest-cli uses [optimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optimist) to parse options and non-hyphenated option are mapped to the underscore option (`_`):

- `jest.runCLI({'_': ['test1']}, __dirname, function (success) {...});` runs only test1.js
- `jest.runCLI({'_': ['test1', 'test2']}, __dirname, function (success) {...});`  runs test1.js and test2.js